# If I download Minecraft PE, will I need a Mojang account? If so, will I be able to use that account to access other versions of the game?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Will I be able to access other versions of the game, eg. Windows 10?

Answer (score 1):

- You need a Mojang account to download Minecraft java edition (PC edition).

  If you want to get Minecraft for an Apple or Android device, you will have to pay to download it on the Apple App Store or the Google play store. You will not receive a gift code for this by buying Minecraft java edition.

  It is also noteworthy Minecraft for Windows 10, Minecraft Pocket Edition (on Apple and Android devices), and some console editions are collectively known as Bedrock Edition, which supports crossplay. Bear in mind, however, that some console editions, like Xbox one edition and PS4 edition don’t support crossplay, however you can get Bedrock Edition on an Xbox.

So, in conclusion, you don’t need a Mojang account to download Minecraft pocket edition or Minecraft for Windows 10, these can simply be bought on the relevant platform.

Comment: Playstation doesn't support crossplay, so not every non-Java edition is Bedrock.

Comment: You had to have bought Minecraft Java before a certain date for that gift code

Comment: @inakilbss No, not every non - java edition is bedrock, sorry. I’m forgetting Xbox one edition, but you can get bedrock on an Xbox one. I was also unaware that PlayStation doesn’t support crossplay.

Comment: @brododragon I wasn’t aware of that.

Comment: While these are good points, I’m unsure of whether to include these in my answer as I want to keep it simple.

Comment: By not including this datum, you are misinforming people. Please fix it.

Comment: I have amended my answer, I hope it’s better now.